# How to crop image by yolo annotated data?

Tags: python, opencv, yolov5

I am trying to write a python script which will crop image by annotated data. Can anyone help me?

Image: [image]

Annotated data:

> 0 0.514583 0.716204 0.136458 0.102778

Comment: please review [ask] and [mre]. show your research (googling) and your own effort. -- those values are relative to total width and height... and the first is probably the class or index of annotation or something

Answer (score 1):

The YOLO coordinates mentioned are in format: x_center, y_center, width_box, height_box, normalised wrt image height and width. You can convert it to normal/usual format for drawing rectangle using:

```
x = x_center * image_width
y = y_center * image_height
w = width_box * image_width
h = height_box * image_height
```

If you looking for bounding box format as: xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, then:

```
xmin = int(x - width_box/2)
ymin = int(y - height_box/2)
xmax = int(x + width_box/2)
ymax = int(y + height_box/2)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this >>

```
import cv2, os

image = cv2.imread('/file/path.ext')
lh,lw,_ = image.shape

# now take your coordinates
x,y,w,h = 0.514583, 0.716204, 0.136458, 0.102778
x,y,w,h = int(x*lw), int(y*lh), int(w*lw), int(h*lh) ## to match the bounding box coordinates with actual width, height

boxedImage = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv2.imshow(boxedImage)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please use correct upper case letters. Also add some more information's to you solution. Code-only is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to load your image and annotation files into the program, crop the images using the annotation coordinates, and save the cropped images as new files.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

# Function to display an image using OpenCV
def show_image(image, title='Image'):
    cv2.imshow(title, image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Load the YOLO annotations
annotations_file = r"path/to/annotation.txt"
annotations = np.loadtxt(annotations_file, delimiter=" ")

# Load the image
image_file = r"path/to/image.jpg"
image = cv2.imread(image_file)
print(image.shape)
# Convert the YOLO annotations to pixel coordinates
image_height, image_width, _ = image.shape

x_center = annotations[1]
y_center = annotations[2]
width = annotations[3]
height = annotations[4]
x_min = int((x_center - width / 2) * image_width)
y_min = int((y_center - height / 2) * image_height)
x_max = int((x_center + width / 2) * image_width)
y_max = int((y_center + height / 2) * image_height)

print("x_min:", x_min)
print("y_min:", y_min)
print("x_max:", x_max)
print("y_max:", y_max)
# Crop the image
cropped_image = image[y_min:y_max, x_min:x_max]

# Show the cropped image
show_image(cropped_image)


# Save the cropped image
output_dir = r"path/to/crop_files_dir"
if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
    os.makedirs(output_dir)
output_file = os.path.join(output_dir, "cropped_image.jpg")
cv2.imwrite(output_file, cropped_image)
```

original image[image]

cropped image[image]